# How i can make a http get request in genexus?

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to make a http get request in genexus, but in the object `httpclient` i can't find the property that have the answer and the method `Execute()` don't return the response of the request.

I need to copulate the json response in one SDT.

I try something like:

```
&httpClient = new()
&httpClient.BaseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + &LocalLatitudeA + ',' + &LocalLongitudeA + '&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
&httpClient.Execute('GET', &httpClient.BaseUrl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to retrieve data from an HTTP endpoint and load a SDT with the result:

```
&HttpClient.Execute(!"GET", !"https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
&Users.FromJson(&HttpClient.ToString())
```

`&HttpClient.ToString()` returns the response as a string, and `&Users.FromJson()` loads the `&Users` SDT with the received data.